# removing py files and retaining pyc files breaks inspection code

Tags: python, bytecode, inspect

The function below works just fine. But if I remove all `py` files (and leave the `pyc`s intact) then I get an error:

To explain what I mean by 'intact' here is more or less what I did:
1. write a bunch of py files and stick them in a friendly directory structure
2. test code code. It works
3. compile all py files to get pyc files
4. delete py files 
5. test code. It fails

The function:

```
def get_module_name_and_line():
    """
    return the name of the module from which the method calling this method was called.
    """
    import inspect
    lStack = inspect.stack()
    oStk = lStack[2]
    oMod = inspect.getmodule(oStk[0])         
    oInfo = inspect.getframeinfo(oStk[0])
    sName = oMod.__name__    #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ERROR HERE
    iLine = oInfo.lineno
    return sName,iLine
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

So `oMod` is `None` in this error. If the py files are around then `oMod` is never `None`.

The question:

Why does inspect only return a module if py files are intact? How can I make this function work without py files.

Full Traceback:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/criticalid/programs/damn.py", line 630, in <module>
File "/home/criticalid/programs/golly/class_foo.py", line 121, in moo
File "/home/criticalid/programs/golly/class_foo.py", line 151, in get_module_name_and_line
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "py files are intact". In this code I guess you could try `sname = oMod.__name if oMod else 'Unknown Name'` and the same for iLine. This way your method will at least return

Comment: @RobertEkendahl: intact means not deleted. If I have py files everything works. If I have just the pyc files then it breaks

Comment: @Sheena: right, with no `.py` source files the traceback is a lot.. sparser too. It does make it clear that your exception is not in the `getmodule()` call, just that that returns `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: exactly. But I don't know why it returns `None`. The function is being called in exactly the same way, the only difference is the lack of py files. Could it be that the inpect module needs py files to function properly? I assumed that dropping the py files wouldn't make a difference because the bytecode would be exactly the same in either case.

Comment: Have you tried not deleting your source code? .pyc files are an undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: @Antimony: But I really really want to delete my source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. It assumes that all modules are in packages within the current working directory. And it doesn't return the `__main__` module, rather its file name.

I'm sure there is a better solution but this solves my problems.

```
def get_module_name_and_line():
    """
    return the name of the module from which the method calling this method was called.
    """
    def get_name_from_path(sPath):
        import os
        sCWD = os.getcwd()
        lCWD = list(os.path.split(sCWD))
        lPath = list(os.path.split(sPath))
        lPath[-1] = '.'.join(lPath[-1].split('.')[:-1])   #remove file extension
        lRet = [s for s in lPath[len(lCWD)-1:]]
        return '.'.join(lRet)

    import inspect
    lStack = inspect.stack()
    oStk = lStack[2]
    iLine = inspect.getlineno(oStk[0])
    sName = get_name_from_path(inspect.getfile(oStk[0]))
    return sName,iLine
```